# Quasar File Picker not working on android build

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I want to pick a file with this component on android build. it worked on the web, but after android build, it does not work.

```
<q-file
   v-model="file"
   label="Change Profile Picture"
   use-chips
   accept=".jpg, .png image/*"
   style="width: 200px"
 />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo in your `accept` rule. You missed a comma after `.png`

`accept=".jpg, .png, image/*"`